# SageMakerRuntime invokeEndpoint: Parsing this JSON is giving me undefined

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to invoke function `invokeEndpoint` and parse response. I am getting data as `undefined`

I tried to parse this JSON but I can't figure out why it's giving me `undefined`

```
sagemakerruntime.invokeEndpoint(params2, function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("INVOKE ENDPOINT ERROR!!!" + err);
  } else {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
  }
});
```

**JSON printed:**

```
{
    "ContentType": "text/csv; charset=utf-8",
    "InvokedProductionVariant": "variant-name-1",
    "Body": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            123,
            34,
            54,
            50,
            102,
            55,
            48,
            51,
            53,
            102,
            45,
            99,
            102,
            52,
            52,
            45,
            52,
            53,
            50,
            50,
            99,
            100,
            49,
            48,
            50,
            49,
            51,
            97,
            51,
            52,
            52,
            34,
            58,
            32,
            34,
            81

        ]
    }
}
```

Tried:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(result["Body"].data));
```

Keeps giving me undefine.. unsure why. Tried doing `result["Body"].data.toString('utf8');` doesn't work either. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's working fine for me. It printed `[123,68,69,34,125]`.

Comment: where did u get this response ?? look like buffer object

Comment: try : console.log(JSON.stringify(result["Body"].data.toString('utf8')));

Comment: ```Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined``` yeah it's buffer. but to String isn't working

Comment: Log `result["Body"]`. what is the output?

Comment: which API u getting this ?? this is not son. this is object.. Which library u are using..

Comment: From AWS sagemaker. This is the entire output as JSON

Comment: can u add the code, where u getting it. This is not JSON, I guess there will be method to get data

Comment: ya i put it above

Comment: i added solution, seems body is buffer type..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to doc: [SageMakerRuntime.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SageMakerRuntime.html), `Body` is `buffer` type.

Try this:

```
sagemakerruntime.invokeEndpoint(params2, function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("INVOKE ENDPOINT ERROR!!!" + err);
  } else {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result.Body.toString('utf8')));
  }
});
```